# How to find future (planned) versions of Docker?

Tags: docker

I need to know a rough release date for the next Docker version(s) or the version scheme they are using for their releases (like "a new version every 3 months" or similar).

So I can plan updates in advance to reserve time for them.

Where might I find information about upcoming Docker releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're talking about Docker Engine for Linux.

Docker doesn't plan releases like that currently. What they do is:

Release major and minor versions on GitHub: https://github.com/moby/moby/releases

Put release notes in their docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes

The version number is date based on the month they begin the release process, so the current version "20.10" started its release process in October, 2020 and was eventually released in December, 2020. The last major release before that was 19.03.

Finally, you can see what they are working on (features) and what's next on their Roadmap https://github.com/docker/roadmap/projects/1

Comment: Cheers Bret, that sheds some light on it. So I guess hard to plan for those updates then. We'll make the best of it, thank you for your time!